# Removing Mask Color LWA_COLORKEY

Tags: delphi, winapi, vcl, layered-windows

`LWA_COLORKEY` is leaving mask color over Text on transparent. Is it possible to remove it and make transparent neat and clean?

```
Form1.Color:=clAqua;
SetWindowLong(Form1.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,  GetWindowLong(Form1.Handle, 
    GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_LAYERED );
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Form1.Handle, Form1.Color, 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMiNQ.jpg it's leaving `clAqua`.

Comment: To make your question more accessible, you should probably try to explain the context a bit more. For instance, if you mention that you are using [layered windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-windows#using-layered-windows) and the [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes) function to create a transparent form, more people might understand the problem. Not as many will immediately recognise the `LWA_COLORKEY` flag. And a minimal sample project would be really great.

Comment: Please use the Image button on the toolbar to add mages, instead of your own link. It's required that the image be on SO's imgur so that it remains available for future readers of this question. Please [edit] your question to properly post the image; I made all of the other formatting changes for you.

Comment: Two observations: (1) You don't need to use `SetWindowLong` and `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`, at least not in fairly recent Delphi versions. Just set the form's `TransparentColor` to `True` and `TransparentColorValue` to your desired colour using the Object Inspector at design time. (2) Either method works: they make all pixels with your designated colour transparent. However, Windows uses ClearType antialiasing to render text, which is great (for text looks horrible without it -- just try to use MS Sans Serif). But this means that the edges of the text have colours *close* to the bg colour...

Comment: ...but they aren't *exactly* the BG colour, so they aren't transparent.

Comment: Antialiased fonts don't mix well with `LWA_COLORKEY`. Try using font with `NONANTIALIASED_QUALITY` in `lfQuality` or `iQuality` or something like that.

Comment: @Daniel Sęk your solutioin is absolutely  correct.Thank you very much bro

Comment: @AkA You can post an answer, if your question has been solved.